# Find limit for $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt {n} +1}$ and then prove in terms of ${e}$ and ${N}$

Tags: analysis

I am attempting to prove if the limit for $S_n = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1} $, exists, and if it exists, what it is?
If the limit exists, proving it in terms of the definition for ${e}$ and ${N}$.

I got the limit by :
$$S_n= \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\Biggl(\frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}}{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}\Biggr)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggl(\frac{1}{1+{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}}\Biggr)=1$$
Having the limit, I assume I can plug it into the definition, as follows:

$${\forall}{e}>0\;\exists{N}={N}{(e)\;s.t.\;\forall\;{n}>{N} \;\vert\;\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1}-1\;\vert} $$
which gives me:
$$\vert\;\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1}-{\frac{\sqrt{n}-1}{\sqrt{n}-1}}\;\vert=\vert\;\frac{\sqrt{n}\,(\sqrt{n}-1)-\;(\sqrt{n}+1)(\sqrt{n}-1)}{(\sqrt{n}+1)(\sqrt{n}-1)}\;\vert=\vert\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{n-1}\vert$$
So now I have 
$$\vert\frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{n-1}\;\vert\leq \frac{1-\sqrt{n}}{n-1}$$
Am I on the right track?
I am unsure of how to proceed from here ?

Comment: the $n-n$ seems like a problem in the final line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for the conjugate here.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then by the Archimedean Property, we have that for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, $\frac1N \lt \varepsilon^2$

See that for $n \ge N$, we have $$\left| \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1} - 1\right| = \left|\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}+1} - \frac{\sqrt{n}+1}{\sqrt{n}+1}\right| = \left|\frac{-1}{\sqrt{n}+1}\right| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+1} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} } \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{N} }<\varepsilon$$

Comment: the reason for the conjugate is that I assumed it would make life simpler, but that is not necessarily the case  in this scenario, so thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake in your calculations. Instead of $|-2|$ in the numerator you should get $|1-\sqrt n|$. Of course, you mis-typed $n-1$ as $n-n$ at the end. Hint for completing the proof: I claim that $n>2$ and $n >\frac 4 {\epsilon^{2}}$ gives $\frac {\sqrt n -1} {n-1} <\epsilon$. For this use the facts that $\sqrt n -1 <\sqrt n$ and $n-1 >\frac n 2$ for $ n>2$.

Comment: Should ${n}$ not be $\geq2$ instead of just $\gt$